# Running two javascript functions in one button click in jade

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I have my html set up and my javascript functions ready but I can't get it to run both at the same time only one runs once  I click the button. I'm using the Jade template engine with Node.js and this is what I have so far:

```
input(type = 'button' value = 'Calcular' onClick = "calculateComission()""calcMonthlyPay()")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function bothFunctions() {
   calculateComission()
   calcMonthlyPay()
}
```

`input(type='button' value='Calcular' onClick="bothFunctions()")`

Answer (score 0):

```
input(type = 'button' value = 'Calcular' onClick = "calculateComission();calcMonthlyPay()")
```

Does this work?

Comment: I did a little test, it works on my side. Maybe your function has some error.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick="calculateComission();calcMonthlyPay();"`

But this is pretty bad. You usually don't want to bind functions inline like that, especially for more complex logic like this. You should probably make a function that calls the other two and bind that, or better bind the event listener in code on page load.

Comment: I need to import the other two scripts into a single one correct?

Comment: That's somewhat of a difficult question to answer. It's probably a good idea to keep the number of scripts you include in a live website to a minimum since requests take time.